# Readonly remote access to AWS console (non graphical)

Tags: ssh, remote, remote-access, aws

I need to provide read only access of my ssh connection to a AWS Ubuntu box to my customer. I don't want to provide him with Graphical access, but I need him to see what I type as I type it on his laptop. This will help me do a demo remotely with use of very low bandwidth.

I have used graphical remote console/control (VNC types) and it takes up a lot of bandwidth (more than I have in my city). I have an unstable internet connection.

I am located in Pune, India. Customers are available in Delhi and Bangalore. My Ubuntu is hosted on AWS.

Comment: I am evaluating http://tmate.io/, found it after I put the question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out tmate.io, could not figure it out quickly, searched more and then found [nutty.io](https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/nuttyapp).

Worked perfectly.

Comment: This answer could be really helpful if you would describe the steps you took.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide him AWS Read only access only SSH specific by using IAM. AWS give the feature of providing the sers with Access Key, While Creating users , you can give only programmatic access type with required permissions